# Convert a C# Library to Net.Core

Tags: visual-studio, .net-4.5, asp.net5

As .NET Core is getting nearer, I will start to convert our Library to NET-Core, so that it could be used from our old Code (Net 4.5) and Net Core! But for me it is not clear what Type should my Library be. I've no "Net-Core" Project Type in VS2015! Do I need to use old school "PCL" Library? Or how do I do it?

Comment: It is not as "old school" as you assume.   .NETCore will never be a replacement for the desktop version of .NET, it is not what they are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I know. But PCL's are old-school I thought! As PCL show only the smallest combined set of APIs

Comment: Changed the tags, as this discussion was about RC1. Users should now upgrade to RC2, http://dot.net

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> But for me it is not clear what Type should my Library be. I've no "Net-Core" Project Type in VS2015! Do I need to use old school "PCL" Library? Or how do I do it?

Use the **Web > Class Library (Package)** type.

- File > New > Project
- Web > Class Library (Package)

[image: Class Library (Package)]

The screenshot is from [Visual Studio Community 2015 Update 2](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2015-update2-vs.aspx) with [ASP.NET 5 RC1 installed](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=627627). Its `project.json` targets two frameworks: .NET 4.5.1 and .NET 5.4 ([renamed to .NET Core.](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNET5IsDeadIntroducingASPNETCore10AndNETCore10.aspx))

```
{
  // other properties deleted for clarity

  "frameworks": {
    "net451": { },
    "dotnet5.4": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.CSharp": "4.0.1-beta-23516",
        "System.Collections": "4.0.11-beta-23516",
        "System.Linq": "4.0.1-beta-23516",
        "System.Runtime": "4.0.21-beta-23516",
        "System.Threading": "4.0.11-beta-23516"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Tip.** When you're upgrading your class library, [run the .NET Portability Analyser](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/1177943e-cfb7-4822-a8a6-e56c7905292b) on the existing code. It will show the classes & members that must change.

Comment: There si no project.json anymore.

Answer (score 3):

At this point, at RC1, you can use the [ASP.NET 5](https://get.asp.net/) stuff, with DNX.
There's project type `Class Library`, with project extension *xproj*.

Keep in mind a lot is changing, including [DNX will be retired](https://github.com/aspnet/dnx) in favor of *dotnet cli*, and more importantly the renaming of [ASP.NET 5 to ASP.NET Core 1.0](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNET5IsDeadIntroducingASPNETCore10AndNETCore10.aspx)

You can target [*dnxcore5* (or one of those new monikers)](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/Documentation/architecture/net-platform-standard.md) when using those project templates.

Answering your comment:

When you install ASP.NET 5, new Visual Studio project templates are added for you. For Web projects. Class Libraries and Console application. All using `project.json`.

Their [roadmap has RC2 date as TBD](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/Roadmap) since they announced the renaming of things. No dates yet.

Comment: Is there a timescale when there will be new Project Types as a Template? I thought the new netcore libs use "json" as project format? Will they be included in VS?